# Can I easily get vim to syntax-highlight CUDA PTX files?

Tags: vim, automation, cuda, syntax-highlighting, ptx

VIM (8.1) has support for CUDA files, at least on Debian/Devuan, via vim81/syntax/cuda.vim . But - there's no such highlighting for PTX files.

One idea I've had is trying to lift something from godbolt's codebase - as they do highlight their PTX output. But I couldn't find where the magic happens in their codebase.

So - is there an easy way, other than rolling my own syntax file, to highlight PTX files in vim?

Comment: The easy way would be to copy the syntax script of a language with a similar syntax and start from there. The hard way would be to start from scratch with `:help syntax` opened.

Comment: @talonmies: Removed that part.

Comment: Use one of the assembly language syntax rules as a base -- usually they have some regexes for register parsing and a list of reserve words for instructions. PTX will be more complex because of the suffix syntax rules but it shouldn't be that hard to get something basic to work

Comment: Also https://github.com/compiler-explorer/compiler-explorer/blob/711ffdb041159265bd184421fb53dda9359fde48/static/modes/ptx-mode.js -- literally typed PTX into search box on the godbolt source page at github

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>(An initial answer based on @talonmies' suggestions.)</sub>

PTX is [officially described](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/parallel-thread-execution/index.html#syntax) to have:

> an assembly-language style syntax with instruction operation codes and operands

so it should be not-so-different to base PTX syntax highlighting on whatever is used for assembly.

Now, assembly languages have two popular variants in terms of syntax: [AT&T style and Intel-style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_assembly_language#Syntax); PTX is AT&T style. That means you need to carefully check whether your basis syntax is Intel-only, AT&T-only or both. In the first case - look for something else; in the second case you'll need some more adaptation, and in the third case a bit less.

Focusing in on vim, you'll find an assembly syntax file in `/usr/share/vim/vim81/syntax/asm.vim` (exact path depends on your installation and vim version of course). It says "GNU Assembler", and the default syntax for that one is AT&T, so hopefully that's what it is.

You'll need to modify that - although even without modification, it would probably work reasonably well already. So start by:

```
cd /usr/share/vim/vim81
cp syntax/asm.vim syntax/ptx.vim
```

then use `sed syntax/ptx.vim` to change the `current_syntax` value to ptx.

Finally, in `filetype.vim`, replicate the line which loads the Assembly syntax file. Note that there is a complex load function which needs to be explored and adapted (or dropped).